# Cannot create new app in Sencha Touch 2.1.1

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

So I decided to play with Sencha.

when I run app create command I have this:

```
D:\DevProjects\sencha-touch-2.1.1-commercial>sencha app create MyApp /my/t1
ERROR: Failed to exec (java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar C:\Users\Cherven\bin\Sencha\Cmd\3.1.0.256\sencha.jar  app create M
yApp /my/t1) - The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Seem like you're missing something. Please follow the official [guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/guide/command-section-2).

So basically, you need to have other 3 things besides Sencha SDK that I'm assume you've already downloaded correctly which are: [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), [Sencha CMD](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) and [Compass](http://compass-style.org/).

Finally, you need to use `generate` instead of `create` to generete new app using `Sencha Cmd`:

```
sencha generate app MyApp /path/to/MyApp
```